# Как повернуть изображение в файле?

Tags: c#, .net

Многие наверняка часто встречались с небольшой, но распространённой проблемой, когда изображение сохранённое в графическом файле имеет не удобную для просмотра ориентацию, и открывается программами просмотра не под тем углом, под каким пользователю наверняка хотелось бы просматривать это. К счастью, даже самые примитивные программы просмотра изображений, нередко дают пользователю возможность повернуть изображение, хотя бы на углы кратные 90°. Некоторые программы, в том числе даже встроенные оболочки современных фотоаппаратов, могут даже сами предугадать, на какой угол нужно повернуть неверно сориентированный файл изображения, и отобразить пользователю его под нужным углом.

Какими средствами языка C# и платформы .Net можно реализовать возможность изменить файл с изображением, повернув второе на заданный угол, и сохранив это изменение в первом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы иметь возможность изменить изображение в файле. Нужно получить объект Image из файла, произвести поворот для этого объекта, записать Image в файл. Используя метод приведённый в ответе `user3373603`, позволяющий повернуть изображение на произвольный угол:

```
Image img = null;
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    img = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
if (img != null)
{  
    img = RotateImage(img, angle); //angle - угол в градусах
    img.Save(filepath);
}
```

Либо, если достаточно поворотов на углы кратные 90° + бонус в виде возможности отражения изображения:

```
/// <summary>
/// Повернуть изображение в файле на угол и (или) отразить по оси
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filepath">путь к файлу</param>
/// <param name="rft">Член перечисления System.Drawing.RotateFlipType, указывающий тип
///  поворота и зеркального отражения, который нужно применить к изображению</param>
public static void RotateImageFile(string filepath, System.Drawing.RotateFlipType rft)
{
   Image img = null;
   using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
   {
       img = Image.FromStream(stream);
   }
   if (img != null)
   {  
       img.RotateFlip(rft);
       img.Save(filepath);
   }
}
```

Comment: основной плюс этого метода - то, что он просто меняет флаг RotateFlip в файле, а не разворачивает саму картинку.

Answer (score 3):

```
/// <summary>
/// поворачивает изображение по часовой стрелке или против часовой стрелки
/// </summary>
/// <param name="img">изображение</param>
/// <param name="rotationAngle">угол (в градусах).
/// Положительные числа - по часовой стрелке
/// отрицательные - против часовой стрелки
/// </param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Image RotateImage(Image img, float rotationAngle)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);

    Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

    gfx.TranslateTransform((float)bmp.Width / 2, (float)bmp.Height / 2);

    gfx.RotateTransform(rotationAngle);

    gfx.TranslateTransform(-(float)bmp.Width / 2, -(float)bmp.Height / 2);

    gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    gfx.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));

    gfx.Dispose();

    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: вопрос про файл, а не объект Image

Comment: [посмотри тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379764/how-to-rotate-image-in-file-in-c-sharp-wpf-application)

Answer (score 1):

Ваша функция будет резать изображение, потому что не рассчитаны новые размеры, при повороте размеры будут меняться и все что не входит в прежний размер будет отсекаться

```
const double DegToRad = 0.017453292519943295;

static float NormalizeAngle(float angle)
    {
        angle %= 360;
        if (angle < 0)
            angle += 360;
        return angle;
    }

static  System.Drawing.Image RotateImage(string fileName, float angle)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image image = null;
            using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
            {
                image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
            }

            angle = NormalizeAngle(angle);
            if(angle % 90 == 0)
                switch(angle)
                {
                    case 0:
                        return image;
                    case 90:
                        image.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                        return image;
                    case 180:
                        image.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                        return image;
                    case 270:
                        image.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                        return image;
                }

            float sin = (float)Math.Sin(angle % 90 * DegToRad);
            float cos = (float)Math.Cos(angle % 90 * DegToRad);
            float oldWidth = image.Width;
            float oldHeight = image.Height;
            float newWidth = 0f;
            float newHeight = 0f;
            float originX = 0f;
            float originY = 0f;

            if ((angle > 0 && angle < 90) || (angle > 180 && angle < 270))
            {
                newWidth = sin * oldHeight + cos * oldWidth;
                newHeight = sin * oldWidth + cos * oldHeight;

                if (angle < 90)
                {
                    originX = sin * oldHeight;
                    originY = 0f;
                }
                else
                {
                    originX = cos * oldWidth;
                    originY = newHeight;
                }
            }
            else if ((angle > 90 && angle < 180) || (angle > 270 && angle < 360))
            {
                newHeight = sin * oldHeight + cos * oldWidth;
                newWidth = sin * oldWidth + cos * oldHeight;
                if (angle < 180)
                {
                    originX = newWidth;
                    originY = sin * oldHeight;
                }
                else
                {
                    originX = 0f;
                    originY = cos * oldWidth;
                }
            }

            System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap((int)newWidth, (int)newHeight);
            bmp.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);
            using (System.Drawing.Graphics gr = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                gr.TranslateTransform(originX, originY);
                gr.RotateTransform(angle);
                gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                gr.DrawImage(image, new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0));
            }

            return bmp;
        }
```

Может быть этот код выглядит не очень красиво (поправьте, кто знает как лучше, буду очень благодарен), но он работает правильно и изображение, которое возвращает функция не обрезано, а вписано в новые размеры полностью и его уже можно сохранять в файл.